# What are the better HDR software apps for the mac?

Tags: lightroom, software, post-processing, hdr, macintosh

I am thinking about doing some more HDR photos and thinking about the software side.  I have CS5 but have never been happy about the speed or the quality of the final images.  I have heard about Imagematix and like what I see.  Any other ideas or suggestions for OS X?

I use Lightroom for my primary editing so integration with it would be a bonus.

Answer (score 4):

[Luminance HDR](http://qtpfsgui.sourceforge.net/) is available for Mac as well as for other platforms. It is free and open source. The definition of "better" and "quality" may vary, but it doesn't cost money to try.

[Flickr group with the samples](http://www.flickriver.com/groups/qtpfsgui/pool/interesting/)

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Photomatix Pro version 3 for a while. It's good, but a bit geeky and doesn't really help you find a good image. I've been experimenting iwth Nik Software's HDR Efex and it's a nice step forward but I'm not yet ready to commit to it. I'm just starting to test Photomatix 4 to see whether i'll move forward with it or Nik's software. Nik has a demo you can download and try out. I like it's integration with Lightroom, but on my Mac I found it a bit laggy. Probably not surprising given how much data is being manipulated,a nd less laggy than Photomatix 3.

Okay, just did a quick test with photomatix 4. Initial thought -- definitely a step up from photomatix 3; still kinda geeky. Faster than HDR Efex by Nik but not as user friendly. The program seems to turn out images more on the "grunge" side by default (not a suprise given Trey Ratliff is an advisor) but you can tone it down. I'm going to experiment more, but right now, I'm (surprisingly enough) preferring Photomatix over HDR efex. I'm a big fan of Nik's software, I didn't expect that.

Here are some quick samples:

unprocessed image:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/chuqui/5207965359/

image out of HDR Efex Pro:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/chuqui/5208563906/

image out of Photomatix 4:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/chuqui/5275434248/

now, don't consider any of these "final" (and the subject matter isn't great, but it was handy). I tried to image them to the same general feel (i.e. "my bias" vs. the program's inate bias on how it ought to be rendered). comparing them, I think I desaturated the phtomatix more.

Both are nice tools. HDR efex is more user friendly, I think the rendering tool in Photomatix is more mature, at least on initial tests, and faster.

Answer (score 0):

At my point of view the best is the one included in Photoshop CS5 (http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop/photoshop/whatsnew/index_rr.html). It's precise and professional, you can also quickly reapply previous settings and the integration in the adobe suite is a must.

You can also try Hydra (http://www.creaceed.com/hydra/), it's integrate weel in Aperture like Photomatix.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Lightroom HDR capabilities for couple of years. It's pretty good. We've also released our own HDR software in November, called Aurora HDR. You're welcome to give it a try: [Aurora HDR for Mac](http://aurorahdr.com).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Macphun Aurora HDR. It's pretty incredible.

`http://aurorahdr.com/`